# Tableview cell does not showing cell information from array

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I have multiple tables in my project, but I stuck in one situation.
From one of my array, I can't get the output and my tableview gets empty showing to me.
Help me.

thanks

```
if (tableView==tableSide)
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell1";
    UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell1 == nil)
    {

        cell1 = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    cell1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    cell1.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
    cell1.textLabel.text=[arrSideBarMenu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell1.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;

    return cell1;
}
```

Comment: What is your arrSideBarMenu? how do you allocate it?

Comment: Can you check whether you are getting the value of arrSideBarMenu??

Comment: check whether u setting tableview datasource and also check ur cell identifier name in storyboard.